# My code loop through urls but not pages in urls Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, try-except

I am trying to extract names and comments from url and my code loops through urls but not pages with in it

len(name) gives 37

```
urls = ['https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/','https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise-control-sensor-blockage-446041/']

name=[]

for url in urls:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for item in range(1,3):
            response = req.get(f"{url}index{item}/")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
            posts = soup.find(id = "posts")
            threadtitle = soup.find('h1',attrs={"class":"threadtitle"})
            for item in soup.findAll('a',attrs={"class":"bigusername"}):
                result = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
                name.append(result)
```

where as when I am trying to run this code

```
for url in urls:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for item in range(1,3):
            response = req.get(f"{url}index{item}/")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
            posts = soup.find(id = "posts")
            threadtitle = soup.find('h1',attrs={"class":"threadtitle"})
        for item in soup.find_all('div', class_="ism-true"):
            try:
                item.find('div', class_="panel alt2").extract()                  
            except AttributeError:
                pass 
            try:
                item.find('label').extract()
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            result = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
            comments1.append(item.text.strip())
```

len(comments1) gives only 17 it is only extracting page2 which is the last page in the range. How can I make sure that my code loops through all the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop through all the pages you can target the next link until it is disabled.

**Code**:

```
urls = ['https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/',
        'https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise-control-sensor-blockage-446041/']

name = []

for url in urls:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        index = 1
        while (True):

            # Checking url here
            print(url + "index{}/".format(index))
            response = req.get(url + "index{}/".format(index))
            index = index + 1
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

            posts = soup.find(id="posts")
            threadtitle = soup.find('h1', attrs={"class": "threadtitle"})
            for item in soup.findAll('a', attrs={"class": "bigusername"}):
                result = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
                name.append(result)
            # Check here next link is disable.
            if 'disabled' in soup.select_one('a#mb_pagenext').attrs['class'][-1]:
                break

print(len(name))
```

On console you can see it prints all the pages urls and total names count.

```
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index1/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index2/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index3/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index4/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index5/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index6/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index7/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index8/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index9/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index10/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index11/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index12/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index13/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index14/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index15/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index16/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index17/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index18/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index19/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index20/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index21/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index22/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index23/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index24/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index25/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index26/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index27/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-adaptive-cruise-control-415450/index28/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise-control-sensor-blockage-446041/index1/
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise-control-sensor-blockage-446041/index2/
280
```

Comment: the above code loops through pages but scrapes upto until last page. It skips last page to scrape.

Comment: @anonymous13 : Sorry My mistake.Just order the if condition down after ferthcing the records.Try updated code I have done changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code very carefully runs through both index values in `range(1,3)`, ignoring the results of your fetches.  After you exit that loop, *then* you operate on the leftover value of `soup`, which is the last one of the previous loop.

If you want to iterate over each `soup`'s contents, you have to indent the second loop to make it an inner loop:

```
    ...
        threadtitle = soup.find('h1',attrs={"class":"threadtitle"})
        for inner in soup.find_all('div', class_="ism-true"):
            try:
                inner.find('div', class_="panel alt2").extract() 
        ...
```

Does that get you going?